# ¿Cómo Optimizar tiempo de script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un script (por el largo del mismo no lo coloco aquí) del cual para fines de resolver mi consulta coloco el plan de ejecución, el script se demora  00:00:04.271 en en ejecutarse, no he logrado reducir este tiempo, he intentado con varios planes de ejecución sin éxito alguno. Ademas no logro establecer con claridad que es lo que mas impacta en ese tiempo, pienso de la función "*Compute Scalar*" derivada del uso de ROW_NUMBER, puede ser en parte el problema.

Podrían por favor darme alguna idea sobre esto, gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como mencione, el sitio no permite pegar todo el texto del script, subo una imagen como referencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito para agregar DER.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito para adjuntar conteo de registros por tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tarda 4 segundos? sobre cuantos registros? hay por lo menos 12 tablas ahi.. no se como esperas que te digamos que mejorar, sin ver el DER y la query y la cantidad de datos que usas.

Comment: Entiendo, agregare los detalles editando la pregunta.

Comment: Y cual es tu Query

Comment: Segun se ve en la imagen  el indice `Enferemedad_Paciente_FichaIOS` es de las tablas que mas registros esta procesando y mas costo de CPU lleva, podrias pensar, en el caso de no tenerlo, en alguna estrategia de particionamiento de los datos

Comment: No me parece ilogico que tarde 4 segundos con semejante query. por mas pocos que sean los registros, la logica de obtencion de los datos por lo poco que se ve es terrible. Es mas.. con tan pocos registros, tantos joins, group by y otras cosas en el medio, me parece que en este momento tu peor costo es I/O... la base es un sql-server particionado en varios servidores?

Comment: Es mas.. que estas tratando de buscar con este query? el ultimo examen de cada paciente? puede que la estrategia sea plantear eso de otra manera, como una tabla que una cada paciente con su ultimo examen, y esa tabla se actualize cada vez que aparezca otro..

Comment: En este recurso de gDrive coloque la estructura y data de las tablas del modelo de datos sobre el que estoy trabajando y el script que utilizo:
 [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzEGjPFntT1-bFBDRDYyVDhpRjA/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Script uutilizado: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzEGjPFntT1-U0ZsMHpNdl9reWs/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: y el resultado de tu consulta, qué es lo que entrega?, cuál es la lógica detrás?

Comment: Yo trabajo sobre un modelo de datos que alguien mas creo, para suplir un requerimiento del usuario, el requerimiento puntual es generar una matriz de datos, básicamente datos  históricos de pacientes, esta matriz es mi tabla resultante... de la ejecución del script en mención. Esta matriz resultante se exporta seguidamente a un sistema de análisis estadístico llamado SPSS.

Comment: La necesidad de optimizarlo se deriva de que, el script se ejecuta desde una aplicación web , adicionalmente  el script que vez se genera de manera dinámica, es decir el usuario elige las tablas y columnas que desea integrar a la matriz de datos

Comment: y 4 segundos te parece mucho?

Comment: Lo raro.. es que pare exportar datos a SPSS no se hace asi. Hay herramientas de extraccion para evitar estas clases de procesos. y menos que menos se hace web... SPSS ya deberia tener los datos a procesar.. pre procesados...

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi , En efecto... 4 segundos es lo que dura este proceso, pero adicionalmente tengo que aplicar algunos catálogos a los valores, lo que toma otro par de segundos mas. No tenia conocimiento sobre una herramienta de extracción, podrías mencionar una, quizás mi solución vaya por esa vía.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo problema y después de mucho investigar en internet me di cuenta de muchos errores que estaba cometiendo en la elaboración de mis consultas, primero que nada veo que utilizas mucho el Left join esto esta estrofiando mucho el tiempo de respuesta de tu consulta ya que esta instrucción te esta devolviendo todo el contenido  y las coincidencias de las tablas que estas utilizando, es decir sql está procesando más información de la que podrías necesitar como lo muestra la sig figura:

[image: Como lo muestra la imagen estas trallendo todos los rejistros de la primer tabla y las concidencias de la segunda]

un inner join simpre va a ser mas eficiente y mas rapido Ademas es nesesario crear los indices correspondientes a los parametros de busqueda que estas utilizando esto optimiza mucho tus consultas. por ultimo las sub consultas dentro de la sentencia join es un sobre procesamiento para el motor de busqueda de sql, creo que debes optar por otra manera de traerte la informacion que vas a utilizar en esta consulta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @UrielSoto. Sin embargo los left join me son necesarios porque los registros pueden existir o no en las tablas del modelo, por otro lado, tienes razón, debo encontrar un modelo mas eficiente para reducir el numero de lefft joins ...